# Show dataset result grouped by columns in RDLC

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I have as a result of a sql query the following data:

```
Name Company  
A      XXX  
B      XXX  
C      YYY  
D      XXX  
E      YYY  
F      ZZZ
```

And I want to show it in a RDLC report as shown below:

```
Company XXX   Company YYY     Company ZZZ
A                C                F
B                E  
D
```

I've read that I need to use a Matrix element for this but I'm not able to do it right. Any advice?

Comment: Thanks for edition, that's the way I wanted to present the question

Comment: When you say "I'm not able to do it right" - can you clarify? Are you getting errors? Did you try to go through any tutorial? Something like this should help: http://ssrstutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/10/lesson-16-drilldown-matrix-reports.html

Comment: I've tried some tutorials but the result is that I end with a chart with names on the left and companies on the top and only a value when name A matches Company XXX, name C matches company YYY and so on. I will check the link you've given to me and see if that helps